# Unable to Install f.lux

Tags: 16.04, f.lux

I am trying to install f.lux through ppa `ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux` . I am getting the following error.

```
me@mysys:~$ sudo apt-get install fluxgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fluxgui : Depends: python-appindicator (>= 0.0.19) but it is not installable
           Depends: python-gconf (>= 2.28.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am able to finish sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-update successfully.Still flux installation is failing.

Comment: Perhaps you can run `apt-get update` and add the output.

Comment: Do you have 'universe' enabled?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-appindicator shows the first to be in universe, ditto second https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-gconf    (See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for details on repos if needed)